# Django + S3 + Pandas - How to save a dataframe on S3 bucket?

Tags: python, django, pandas, amazon-s3

I am creating a Pandas DataFrame inside a view and I need to save it on my S3 bucket as a csv file. I can store uploaded files normaly, my problem is to create files in a view and store them. Can anyone help?